# Trying to customise FUIAuthPickerViewController and getting error in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm trying to customize `FUIAuthPickerViewController` so that I can have a customized authentication screen as my login screen using FirebaseUI authentication

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder:'

I know there's a bug that stops the `FUIAuthPickerViewController` from being the root view controller, so in `Main.Storyboard` I've added a blank view controller and set the class to be my `CustomLoginViewController` which subclasses `FUIAuthPickerViewController`

Wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction? No idea why I'm getting that error.

Thanks

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseAuthUI

class CustomLoginViewController: FUIAuthPickerViewController {

override init(nibName: String?, bundle: Bundle?, authUI: FUIAuth) {
    super.init(nibName: "FUIAuthPickerViewController", bundle: bundle, authUI: authUI)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if !isUserSignedIn() {
        showLoginView()
    }
}

private func isUserSignedIn() -> Bool {
    guard FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser != nil else { return false }
    return true
}

private func showLoginView() {
    if let authVC = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()?.authViewController() {
        present(authVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

This is my AppDelegate.swift

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, FUIAuthDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var storyboard: UIStoryboard?
var authUI: FUIAuth?

let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [
    FUIGoogleAuth(),
    FUIFacebookAuth()
]

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FIRApp.configure()

    authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
    authUI?.delegate = self
    authUI?.providers = providers

    return true
}

func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith user: FIRUser?, error: Error?) {
    print("SIGNED IN")
}

public func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    let handled = SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)

    return handled || GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
}

func authPickerViewController(forAuthUI authUI: FUIAuth) -> FUIAuthPickerViewController {
    return CustomLoginViewController(authUI: authUI)
}
```

This is the full call stack

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'This coder requires that replaced objects be returned from initWithCoder:'
*** First throw call stack: (   0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001065c1d4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171  1   libobjc.A.dylib    0x000000010602321e objc_exception_throw + 48     2   CoreFoundation       0x000000010662b2b5 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197  3   UIKit       0x0000000104dda1eb UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 758   4   UIKit   0x0000000104dd9eee -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 98     5   UIKit 0x0000000104be5d14 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 178    6   UIKit                               0x0000000104dda1a1 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 684   7   UIKit                      0x0000000104dda357 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1122   8   UIKit  0x0000000104dd9eee -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 98  9   UIKit 0x0000000104be4eb8 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1249  10  UIKit                               0x0000000104fa4f7b -[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:] + 181   11  UIKit             0x00000001047d747d -[UIApplication
_loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 111     12  UIKit                               0x00000001047d7947 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 260    13  UIKit                               0x00000001047d5fa8 -[UIApplication
_runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1406     14  UIKit                               0x00000001047d326d -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188   15  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010925a6cb
__FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24   16  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010925a544
-[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 189    17  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010925a8cd -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45     18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106566761
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17     19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010654b98c
__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556     20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010654ae76 __CFRunLoopRun + 918     21  CoreFoundation            0x000000010654a884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420     22  UIKit               0x00000001047d1aea -[UIApplication _run] + 434  23  UIKit              0x00000001047d7c68 UIApplicationMain + 159   24  Surfshop               0x0000000100f54cbf main + 111    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001073e968d start + 1    26  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by creating a new subclass of UIViewController called MyViewController and set the class property in storyboard to be MyViewController rather than CustomLoginViewController

Comment: It's only 2yrs later but.. any chance you can clarify your answer as I've hit the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54825189/cant-get-background-to-show-on-subclassed-fuiauthpickerviewcontroller)?

If you set class property in storyboard to be `MyViewController`, how does that trigger the subclassed `FUIAuthPickerViewController`?