# Can't get background to show on subclassed FUIAuthPickerViewController

Tags: swift, firebase, firebaseui

So, I subclassed `FUIAuthPickerViewController` for customization purposes but I can't get the background to display. This started happening after updating Firebase pods to the latest version (was working fine on the previous version).

Here's my current set-up.

How I call it (from `AppDelegate`):

```
var authViewController = authUI.authViewController()
self.window!.rootViewController = authViewController
self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

My FUIAuth's delegate method (also in `AppDelegate`):

```
func authPickerViewController(forAuthUI authUI: FUIAuth) -> FUIAuthPickerViewController {
    return AuthViewController(authUI: authUI)
}
```

My subclass:

```
class AuthViewController: FUIAuthPickerViewController {

    var imgView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let backgroundImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "MainBackground")
        imgView = UIImageView(image: backgroundImage)
        imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        self.view.insertSubview(imgView, at: 0)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        imgView.frame = self.view.bounds
    }
}
```

What it looks like:

[image]

If I change the line above from:

`self.view.insertSubview(imgView, at: 0)`

to

`self.view.insertSubview(imgView, at: 1)`

Then I can see the background and not the buttons:

[image]

My pods:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

See [comments on GitHub issue](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues/628) for a workaround.